# Is there a way to make my page not to zoom in when it's opened on different screen size than mine?

Tags: html, css

So I tried to make my code mobile responsive and I figured out how to do it, But comes another problem that I couldn't resolve. The page zooms in(zooms in from the browser so I have to zoom out) whenever I open it on a different screen size (another laptop), So what's the issue here and how can I resolve it ?. Thanks for your help in advance.

**HTML**

```css
  .container{
          max-width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          display: flex;
          padding: 1%;
          }

          body{
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
          background-color: #383C46;
          background-size: contain;
          margin: 0;
          }

          h{

  
          width: 317px;
          height: 59px;
          left: 389px;
          top: 26px;
          font-size: 25px;

          }
          #cinfo{
          cursor: pointer;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          width: 317px;
          height: 59px;
          font-size: 20px;
          text-decoration: none;
          }
          #getstarted{

    
          text-transform: uppercase;
          width: 317px;
          height: 59px;

          font-size: 20px;
          text-decoration: none;
          }
          #home{
        
          text-transform: uppercase;
          width: 317px;
          height: 59px;
          font-size: 20px;
          text-decoration: none;
          }
          img.content {
          position: relative;
          left: 20%;
          width: 240px;
          height: 240px;
          float: left;
          padding: 60px;
          margin-left: 20px;
          margin-top: 150px;
          }
          @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
         .cont {
          width: 100%;
          margin-left: -144px;
          margin-top: -190px;
          padding: 50px;
          }
          }

          #menu, #menu ul{
    
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
          }
    
           .menu{
  
            padding-bottom: 0.2%;
            padding-top:1%;
            padding-left: 10%;
            padding-right:10%;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 1100px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            background-color: #2a2e33;
            border-radius: 6px;
            box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            }
            .menu-item{
            min-width: 200px;
            }
            .menu::before, #menu::after{
             content: '';
            display: table;
            }
            .menu:after{
            clear: both;
            } 
            .menu li {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
     
            }
            .menu .headd{
 
            left: -10%;
            top: -20%;
            font-size: 27x;
            color:white;
            }  

            .menu a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color:white;
            } 

            .menu ul{
            padding-left: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 72px;
            left: -10px;
            z-index: 1;
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
            background: black;
            }

            .menu li:hover > ul{
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
            margin: 0;
            }
            .menu ul ul{
            top: 0;
            left: 150px;
            margin: 0 0 0 20px;

            }
            .menu ul li{
            position: relative;
     
            float: none;
            display: block;
            border: 0; 
            background:rgba(255, 249, 249, 0.25);
            text-align: center;
            }
            .menu ul a{
            padding: 10px;
            width: 130px;
            display: block;
            white-space: nowrap;
            float: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            .menu ul a:hover{
             background: rgb(73, 73, 73);
            }

            .headbox{
    
             position: relative;
             left: 100px;
             margin-left: auto ;
             margin-right: auto;
             margin-top: 90px;
             margin-bottom: 60px;
             display: block;
             font-size: 2vh;
             }
             .left-center{

             padding-left: 260px;;
             }
             .lec{
             position: relative;
             margin-left: auto ;
             margin-right: auto;
             margin-top: 90px;
             margin-bottom: 60px;
             display: block;
             }

             @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
            .lec{
            width: 350px;
            height: 286px;
            } 
            .headbox{
            left: -30px;
            }
            .menu {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-left: 1px;
            padding-right: 20px;
      
            }
            .menu .headd{
             position: absolute;
             left: -190px;
        
             }
             .menu a{
              position: relative;
              left: 76px;
              top: 54%;
              padding-right: 40px;
              }
              .menu #home{
              position: relative;
              left: 106%;
              }
           
 
             .left-center{
              padding-top: 10px;
              padding-left: 77px;
               width: 200px;
              height: 150px;
        
              }
             .menu ul a{
              position: relative;
              left: -1px;
              padding: 2px;
              width: 100px;
              display: block;
              white-space: nowrap;
              float: none;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              }
              .menu ul li{
              float: none;
              display: block;
              border: 0; 
              background:rgba(255, 249, 249, 0.25);
        
        
             }
              .menu ul{
              opacity: 1;
              position: absolute;
              top: 38px;
              left: 68px;
              z-index: 1;
              transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
              background: black;
       
              }
              .menu ul ul{
        
              left: 90px;
              padding-left: 20px;
    
              }
              }
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Web Development course</title>
    
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="allcontent.css"> 
     </head>

     <body>

     <div class="container">

        <ul class = "menu"> 
            <li><h style = "padding-right: 120px; padding-left: 50px;" class = "headd">WEB
      Course</h></li>
            <li><a style = "padding-right: 100px;" id = "getstarted" href="allcontent.html">Get 
      started</a></li>
            <li><a style = "padding-right: 100px;"id = "cinfo" >Course Info</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a id = "htm" href="htmlcourse.html">HTML</a>
    
                       <ul>
                           <li><a id = "lec" href="htmlcourse.html">Videos</a>
                           <li><a id = "tut" href="htmltut.html">Lectures</a>
                           <li><a id = "Lab" href="htmllab.html">Labs</a>
                       </ul>
    
                   </li>
    
                   <li><a id = "cs" href="csscourse.html">CSS</a>
    
                       <ul>
                           <li><a id = "cslec" href="csscourse.html">videos</a>
                           <li><a id = "cstut1" href="csstut.html">Lectures</a>
                           <li><a id = "csLab1" href="csslab.html">Labs</a>
                       </ul>
    
                   </li>    
    
                   <li><a id = "java" href="jscourse.html">JavaScript</a>
    
                       <ul>
                           <li><a id = "javalec" href="jscourse.html">videos</a>
                           <li><a id = "javatut" href="jstut.html">Lectures</a>
                           <li><a id = "javaLab" href="jslab.html">Labs</a>
                       </ul>
    
                   </li>
    
                </ul>
                
            </li>
         
            <li><a  id = "home" href="home.html">Home</a></li>     
        </ul>
        </div>
          
        
         <style>
         h, a{
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 41px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            
         }
         img:hover{opacity: 0.6; transform: scale(1.2); transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;}
         img:not(:hover){transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;}
         a:hover{text-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0); transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;}
         a:not(:hover){transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;}

         </style>
        
        
            <div class= "cont">
                <a href = "htmlcourse.html">
                
                   <img class = "content" src ="images/html.png">
                </a> 
                <a href = "csscourse.html">
                    
                   <img class = "content" src ="images/css.png">
                </a>
                <a href = "jscourse.html">
                    
                   <img class = "content" src ="images/js.png">
                </a>
            
           </div>
        
          </div>
    

    

          </body>
          </html>
```

Comment: Please add more details and clarity. I have no idea about what issue you talk about. Also giving absolute valeus as width or margin/padding is quite the opposite of bein repsonive. Same for expecting a same behavior on any screen site is also the opposite of being responsive. Last but not least, you should not sue inline-style outside of e-mail templates. The specificty weight issues you triggering will become quite hard to fix later on.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity, my issue is when i opened my project on my other laptop which has a smaller screen the page by default zooms in, I have to zoom out from the browser by 80% for it to be perfect.

Comment: It doesn't zoom in, the screen is just smaller which makes the code appears bigger. The problem here is that your code is not responsive and thus does not adapt to different screen sizes.